# Lua C api: handling large numbers

Tags: c, lua

I deal with picoseconds in my code (numbers are > 10^12).
C code to pass data to Lua (atime and eventid are both of size_t type)

```
lua_getglobal ( luactx, "timer_callback" );
lua_pushunsigned ( luactx, atime );
lua_pushunsigned ( luactx, eventid );
lua_pcall ( luactx, 2, 0, 0 );
```

Lua function

```
function timer_callback(time, eventid)  
  if eventid == TX_CLOCK then
  out_log(tostring(time)) --result is random garbage
  set_callback(time + 1000000000000, TX_CLOCK)
  return
  end  
end
```

I tried with lua_pushnumber but in result in lua I got negative numbers.

Comment: What version of lua?  5.3 supports `lua_Integer`, which is 64 bits by default.

Comment: I use 5.2 under Win32

Comment: indiv, please make your message as answer. I just build 5.3 from sources, recompiled my application and all worked like a charm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lua, as of 5.3, supports `lua_Integer`, which is 64 bits by default.  From the [reference manual](http://www.lua.org/work/doc/manual.html):

> **lua_Integer**
>
> typedef ... lua_Integer;
>
> The type of integers in Lua.
>
> By default this type is long long (usually a 64-bit two-complement integer), but that can be changed to long or int, usually a 32-bit two-complement integer. (See LUA_INT in luaconf.h.)
>       Lua also defines the constants LUA_MININTEGER and LUA_MAXINTEGER, with the minimum and the maximum values that fit in this type.

Lua 5.2 lua can be coerced into using a different number type fairly easily by editing `luaconf.h`. The number type is defined as `LUA_NUMBER`.

For lua 5.1, you can install the [lnum](http://luaforge.net/projects/lnum/) patch, which will change the integer type.